# Fallback font for Korean in Outlook HTML message

Tags: html, css, .net, windows, outlook

I am trying to compose an HTML email to be readable in Outlook (365 v16).  There will be text embedded within this email which will be of an undetermined language.  When displaying Latin characters, it works fine and I can specify whatever font I like.  However, when I try to display Korean characters, it seems Outlook recognises that the characters are not contained within the standard fonts, and falls back to displaying these characters using the "Batang" font.

I have been told by my Korean colleagues that this is not the preferred font for Korean, which would be "Malgun Gothic".  I can't seem to get Outlook to fall back to this font, however, without specifying it as the font for every message.  I would have thought specifying Malgun on the list of font-family would have informed Outlook to fall back to this one instead, but it always defaults to Batang unless I put Malgun as the very first font on the list (which results in any Latin text looking a little off, and not the font we want for Latin characters).

I have tried using CSS in the html head, inlining it into every

, using the [if mso] workaround, but it seems like Outlook will use the first font it finds on the system, yet fallback to Batang whenever it encounters a character not supported by that font.  I don't know if this is to HTML standard, but it seems Outlook ignores most modern HTML standards anyway.

Any suggestions on how I can have it use a particular font for Korean (or other character sets, we've just had complaints about Korean so far), *without* knowing the language of the text that is being embedded in the email?

(We are using MailKit in .net to compose the email message, so can use any .net packages to help us accomplish this if needed - already using PreMailer.net to inline the CSS)

Comment: Are you able to make it work in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Yes, I can get it to work when I view the email in IE